# How to encapsulate useState of components in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following example code:

```
export function SomeFormComponent() {
    const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState("");
    const [alertTitle, setAlertTitle] = useState("");
    const [alertSeverity, setAlertSeverity] = useState("");


    //to be called at the result of form result
    const setAlert = (title, message, severity) => {
        setAlertTitle(title);
        setAlertMessage(message);
        setAlertSeverity(severity);
    }

    return (<div>
        <FormContents/>
        <Alert severity={alertSeverity}>
          <AlertTitle>{alertTitle}</AlertTitle>
          {alertMessage}
        </Alert>
    </div>)
}
```

It is a form with an alert component, where the result of a fetch is shown. My problem is that I duplicate this code (useState(), setAlert(), ) in each form that my application has. I want to know if there a way to do this without duplicating code.

Comment: Depends what your other alerts look like - hard to say without seeing what's common and what changes

Comment: I'm using Material-UI Alert https://material-ui.com/es/components/alert/

Comment: Same thing applies

Comment: Yes, you can use [`useReducer` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Comment: @CertainPerformance All form componentes use same Alert. What changes in each Form is just the FormContents, useState() calls for each inputs and the api calls methods.

Comment: How exactly do they differ - do you mean you have a different initial value for the `useState`s? A [MCVE] would really be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom hook, and an accompanying component. The hook provides a `setAlert()` function, and an `alert` object that you can spread on the component.

`useAlert` custom hook - you only need a single setState with an object that includes all the values:

```
const useAlert = () => {
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState({ alertMessage: '', alertTitle: '', alertSeverity: '' });
  
  return [
    alert,
    (alertMessage, alertTitle, alertSeverity) => {
      setAlert({ alertMessage, alertTitle, alertSeverity });
    }     
  ]
}
```

`AlertWrapper` component:

```
const AlertWrapper = ({ alertSeverity, alertTitle, alertMessage }) => (
  <Alert severity={alertSeverity}>
    <AlertTitle>{alertTitle}</AlertTitle>
    {alertMessage}
  </Alert>
);
```

Usage:

```
export function SomeFormComponent() {
  const [alert, setAlert] = useAlert();

  // use setAlert in your form
  return (
    <div>
      <FormContents/>
      <AlertWrapper {...alert} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Has it some drawback compared to Shyam solution? In this solutions, the state a json but in Shyam 's is multiple states. Could your solution cause more rerender because the state is a json? Or does it not matter because they are passed to the component as individual props?

Comment: This not a JSON, but a JS object. JSON is textual data file / transport format. Since you update all states together anyway, separating the states no meaning. In addition, this allows you to reuse both the hook, and the component easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a customHook .

```
const useAlert = () => {
  const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState();
  const [alertTitle, setAlertTitle] = useState("");
  const [alertSeverity, setAlertSeverity] = useState("");


  const setAlert = (title, message, severity) => {
      setAlertTitle(title);
      setAlertMessage(message);
      setAlertSeverity(severity);
  }

  return [ alertMessage, alertTitle, alertSeverity, setAlert]
}


export function SomeFormComponent() {
  const [ message, title, severity, setAlert ] = useAlert();

  return (<div>
      <FormContents/>
      <Alert severity={severity}>
        <AlertTitle>{title}</AlertTitle>
        {message}
      </Alert>
  </div>)
}
```